# Using purrr map to iterate list of data frames, extract columns and created a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I am practicing working with the `purrr` package but still fall short. I am trying to use `purrr`'s `map()` function to iterate through a list of data frames and select specific columns to create a new data frame. I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```r
library(tidyverse)
    
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, col1 = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(x = 5:10, col2 = letters[5:10])
df3 <- data.frame(x = 10:15, col3 = letters[10:15])

list_dataframes <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# would like to do something like this
new_dataframe <- map_df(list_dataframes, ~select(., c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
#> Error in `map()`:
#> i In index: 1.
#> Caused by error in `select()`:
#> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `col2` doesn't exist.

#> Backtrace:
#>      x
#>   1. +-purrr::map_df(list_dataframes, ~select(., c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
#>   2. | \-purrr::map(.x, .f, ...)
#>   3. |   \-purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
#>   4. |     +-purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
#>   5. |     | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. |     +-purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
#>   7. |     \-global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
#>   8. |       +-dplyr::select(., c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
#>   9. |       \-dplyr:::select.data.frame(., c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
#>  10. |         \-tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), data = .data, error_call = error_call)
#>  11. |           \-tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
#>  12. |             +-tidyselect:::with_subscript_errors(...)
#>  13. |             | \-rlang::try_fetch(...)
#>  14. |             |   \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  15. |             \-tidyselect:::vars_select_eval(...)
#>  16. |               \-tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
#>  17. |                 \-tidyselect:::eval_c(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
#>  18. |                   \-tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
#>  19. |                     \-tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(new, data_mask, context_mask)
#>  20. |                       \-tidyselect:::eval_c(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
#>  21. |                         \-tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
#>  22. |                           \-tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(new, data_mask, context_mask)
#>  23. |                             \-tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
#>  24. |                               \-tidyselect:::as_indices_impl(...)
#>  25. |                                 \-tidyselect:::chr_as_locations(x, vars, call = call, arg = arg)
#>  26. |                                   \-vctrs::vec_as_location(...)
#>  27. \-vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
#>  28.   \-vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
#>  29.     \-vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
#>  30.       \-rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

LE: `map_df(list_dataframes, ~select_if(., is.character))` works but doesn't bind the columns correctly.

Any help or insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use `one_of`, e.g. `new_dataframe <- map_df(list_dataframes, ~select(., one_of(c("col1", "col2", "col3"))))`?

Comment: Yes, `one_of` works. Still produces warnings because of columns not existing in all data frames, as @Dimitri already suggested. Still feeling silly because I tried `all_of` and of course it game the same error. If you guess a way to pacify the warning it would be great. Any way you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Its actually superseded by `any_of` (see [here](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/all_of.html)).

Comment: You can use `suppressWarnings({...})` for silencing the warnings.

Comment: Yea, i know about `suppressWarnings` but was not the point, `any_of` doesn't produce the warning because it doesn't look for all columns in all data frames. So that solves that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the name "col1" (or col2 or col3) doesn't exist in all your data.tables. You could try :

```
new_dataframe <- map_df(list_dataframes, ~{
return(.x) %>% select(starts_with("col"))
})
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `bind_cols` here?

Comment: Yes, `map_df(list_dataframes, ~{return(.x) %>% select(starts_with("col"))})` works and is easy to understand. Thank you for the explanation as well.

Comment: @Julian `map()` returns a list of data.tables. You can then assemble them in a single data.table using `bind_cols`. If you want to assemble elements from a list in a more complex way, look for `purrr::reduce()`.

Comment: What I meant is that if you remove `bind_cols()` from your code, it produces the same output - hence you could remove it since it does not add any value. The first part of your answer is completely fine though :)

Comment: Before @Claudiu Papasteri's edit, the code was `new_dataframe <- map(list_dataframes, ~{return(.x %>% select(starts_with("col")))
}) %>% bind_cols()` (map instead of map_df), and could be used to bind the three data.tables by columns instead of by rows. I didn't see that the data.frames examples had different nomber of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `map_df` (binding by row) like this

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_df(list_dataframes, ~select(., any_of(c("col1", "col2", "col3"))))

   col1 col2 col3
1     a <NA> <NA>
2     b <NA> <NA>
3     c <NA> <NA>
4     d <NA> <NA>
5     e <NA> <NA>
6     f <NA> <NA>
7  <NA>    e <NA>
8  <NA>    f <NA>
9  <NA>    g <NA>
10 <NA>    h <NA>
11 <NA>    i <NA>
12 <NA>    j <NA>
13 <NA> <NA>    j
14 <NA> <NA>    k
15 <NA> <NA>    l
16 <NA> <NA>    m
17 <NA> <NA>    n
18 <NA> <NA>    o
```

Or if your rows have exactly the same length across lists, than you can use `bind_cols()`, (I changed df1 to `df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:6, col1 = letters[1:6])`)

```
new_dataframe <- map(list_dataframes, ~select(., any_of(c("col1", "col2", "col3"))))
new_dataframe |> bind_cols()

  col1 col2 col3
1    a    e    j
2    b    f    k
3    c    g    l
4    d    h    m
5    e    i    n
6    f    j    o
```